# Google maps V2 android get current location

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

Im trying to place a marker on the position i am, this way:

```
googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_container)).getMap();
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

My question is, how to get coordinates from myLocation, i tried, googleMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude() and googleMap.getMyLocation().getAltitude() right after googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true), but app crashes, another thing i did was Location loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider) but are not the same coordinates and the marker is placed in the wrong place.

How can you people help me?

Comment: Did you check the answer .

Answer (score 0):

```
 SupportMapFragment mf =(SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mMap = mf.getMap();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.setMapType(mMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add these two lines of code to get current location on Maps

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
```

and when you long press on any location on map add this code to get its location

```
googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {

                double alt = arg0.latitude;
                double alo = arg0.longitude;

                MarkerOptions marker1 = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(alt, alo)).title("Lat ="+alt+" Lang="+alo);
                googleMap.addMarker(marker1);

            }
        });
```